# How do I get the same value in php just like encodePassword in spring security framework?

Tags: java, php, encryption, spring-security

I need to get the same value from php as the result obtained using the encodePassword method of the Spring Security ShaPasswordEncoder object.

I do not have permission to modify the corresponding Java code, so php alone should solve this problem.

Java Code :

```
ShaPasswordEncoder shaPasswordEncoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);
shaPasswordEncoder.setIterations(1000);
String password = "123456789";
String salt = "123456";
String hash2 = shaPasswordEncoder.encodePassword(password, salt);
System.out.println(hash2);
```

I tried the following :

```
$password = "123456789"; 
$salt = "123456";

$hash = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, $salt, 1000);
echo 'hash_pbkdf2 result : '.$hash.'<br>';

$out = $salt.$password;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) $out = hash('sha256', $out);
echo 'hash result : '.$out.'<br>';
```

Java Result :

```
9379d5a5fdd899cdf588b075988b9e94d2b3fe5cb44e593dd4a241f4757c8eec
```

php Result :

```
hash_pbkdf2 result : 2794f28c44aa958663637ebeed391b533854fb2f4b7b7d09f521de8c1fe5c6bb
hash result : b0782b680af7a13aeffc61006d2799d69ddc0465c33f376b40d946dd232f62ed
```

I want to make the result value of php equal to the result value of Java. What should I do?

Comment: ShaPasswordEncoder is deprecated and marked for deletion...

Comment: @Ebbe M. Pedersen Thank you for your feedback. ShaPasswordEncoder was available because Spring Security is an older version.

Comment: @DayBreak Just because it’s available in your older version, doesn’t mean it should be used. `ShaPasswordEncoder` was directly replaced by `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` which is *also* now deprecated. From the deprecation notice: “*Digest based password encoding is not considered secure. Instead use an adaptive one way function like BCrypt, Pbkdf2, or SCrypt. Even better use DelegatingPasswordEncoder which supports password upgrades. There are no plans to remove this support. It is deprecated to indicate that this is a legacy implementation and using it is considered insecure.*”

Comment: @MTCoster Thank you for your comment. However, because of my client's request, I must always find a way to get the same results as in ShaPasswordEncoder in php. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the process I went through to figure this out; I’m writing it out in full here to help you learn the process, not just this one solution.

From the source of [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.java) (comments removed for brevity):

```java
public class ShaPasswordEncoder extends MessageDigestPasswordEncoder {
    public ShaPasswordEncoder() {
        this(1);
    }

    public ShaPasswordEncoder(int strength) {
        super("SHA-" + strength);
    }
}
```

Looks like a pretty thin wrapper class to me. Calling `new ShaPasswordEncoder(256)` is effectively the same as calling `new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-256")`, so let’s take a look at the source for [that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.java):

```java
public class MessageDigestPasswordEncoder extends BaseDigestPasswordEncoder {
    private final String algorithm;
    private int iterations = 1;

    [...]

    public String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt) {
        String saltedPass = mergePasswordAndSalt(rawPass, salt, false);   /* 1 */

        MessageDigest messageDigest = getMessageDigest();

        byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest(Utf8.encode(saltedPass));    /* 2 */

        // "stretch" the encoded value if configured to do so
        for (int i = 1; i < this.iterations; i++) {                       /* 3 */
            digest = messageDigest.digest(digest);
        }

        if (getEncodeHashAsBase64()) {
            return Utf8.decode(Base64.encode(digest));
        } else {
            return new String(Hex.encode(digest));                        /* 4 */
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

Ahh, now we’re getting somewhere. There were some additional methods in there, but we only really care about `encodePassword` for now. It works about as you’d expect. From the numbered lines:

1. Salt the password

   - This uses the innocent-looking `mergePasswordAndSalt` method which we’ll take a look at next
2. Hash the salted password

   - Note the UTF-8 encoding here - that will not always be the default
3. Repeatedly hash the output for additional iterations

   - Note that both the input and output of the `messageDigest.digest` method are raw byte arrays, not hex-encoded strings
4. Return a hex-encoded string of the final output

As promised, here’s the source of the [`mergePasswordAndSalt`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.java#L89-L107) method:

```java
protected String mergePasswordAndSalt(String password, Object salt, boolean strict) {
    if (password == null) {                                                              /* 1 */
        password = "";
    }

    if (strict && (salt != null)) {                                                      /* 2 */
        if ((salt.toString().lastIndexOf("{") != -1)
                || (salt.toString().lastIndexOf("}") != -1)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot use { or } in salt.toString()");
        }
    }

    if ((salt == null) || "".equals(salt)) {
        return password;
    } else {
        return password + "{" + salt.toString() + "}";                                   /* 3 */
    }
}
```

Again from the numbered sections:

1. Check for empty password
2. Check for presence of `{` and `}` characters; these are not allowed because of the next point
3. Output the salted password in the form `password{salt}`

Here we see why your attempt at reproducing this algorithm in PHP failed.

From this information, see if you can build up a PHP function that behaves in the same way. I’ll edit in a full PHP solution later tonight when I have access to an environment to test it in.